# How to stop Bitbucket and Git LFS file Duplication

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-lfs

I am using Bitbucket and Git LFS to store binary files for a project I am working on. What I have found is that i very quickly run out of storage and the cause seems to be that each time i push a change LFS will add a new file to the server instead of overwriting the file. I have a particular file that is around 400 MB and if I push i can see it in file storage more than once.

Is there a way to stop this behavior and instead overwrite the file, or is there an easy process to purge the old files before pushing?

Very similar to this post (with no answer): [GIT LFS tracking old data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42521702/5858411)

Comment: If you remove the old files from git LFS, you lose the ability to go back versions in git, one of the primary design goals of git

Comment: Makes perfect sense, but with storage limits there must be some sort of hack to bypass that behavior. Do larger groups / companies seriously pay up for the massive amount of storage needed to support this large amount of file duplication?